# VBA Executing CODE from a ComboBox

Tags: ms-access

I have a very complex process that involves downloading a number of files from different shares, concatenating those files into working tables, manipulating and calculating related information, and then exporting specific fields (and calculations) as reports into a number of Excel workbooks.

I have this process coded so that I can click one button and the entire process will execute end to end. I have a series of text boxes that function as 'indicators' (red - this part failed, green - this part succeeded). As you can imagine, the code for the entire process is HUGE (32 pages when copied into MSWord) and difficult to weed through when I have a problem.

I got it into my mind that I wanted to put the code into a table so that it was much more modular and easier to deal with. I have setup a combo box with the action that I want to take and a second combo box with the report/file/object that I want to work with (ie Delete - Table 2, Acquire - File 1, Export - Report 4). I have been successful at creating the SQL statement to do simple things like del * from tbl_test and execute that from the combo boxes without any issue.

What I need to know is if there is a way to put what is essentially a code snippet into the table (memo field) and then have that vba code execute when I select the matching combos.

IE the code for 'Acquire - File1' is completely VBA code; it maps a network drive, locates the file, downloads the file, and moves it to a directory.

IE the code for 'Scrub - tblMain_Part1' is a combination of vba and sql code; it checks for the existence of a file (vba), if it finds it, it deletes a portion of the main table (sql) and appends the contents of the file it finds (sql), then it updates the monitor to indicate that it is completed (vba). If the file is not found, it changes the monitor box to red and updates a command button caption (vba)

I am NOT a genius with vba, but I hold my own. The thought process I had was that if I can essentially get the code broken into managable chunks in the table, I could call the code smippets in order if I want to run the entire process, or I could just re-execute portions of the code as needed by selecting the action and report/file/object combination.

Any thoughts/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be best to split the code into Subs.  The table you loop through would have a *Sub-Name* field and a *blnSuccess* field.  Your code would loop though the table running each sub and then updating *blnSuccess* based on any errors you receive.  This would give you queryable result set when you try to see what happened.

Comment: So the concept would be to create a series of public subs for the separate code portions. Within the table, have the public sub name and success field (which could be linked to the monitor indicators) but how would I actually get access to execute the code based on the action-report/file/object combo boxes....right now I have been successful using a dlookup to execute simple SQL queries...how would I call the public sub based on those criteria?

Comment: I will improve my answer shortly

Comment: @StevenCrandall: One option would be `Application.Run "NameOfSub"`. If you want to use Functions instead of Subs (so that you can return a value, e.g., a boolean indicating success), you can use `result = Eval("NameOfFunction")`.

Comment: You do not need a table. This is code. You can execute the various subs and functions from buttons. Adding a table is just a way of making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Heinzi What's with this eval stuff? It is code, run it. Do not use a table.

Comment: HelloW You need to stress the importance of error coding for each procedure.

Comment: @Remou: He wants dynamic dispatching of code based on the selection in a ComboBox. Yes, it could also be done with a huge Select Case statement as suggested by Scotch; feel free to upvote his solution if you prefer it. Using `Eval` is just another option to solve the problem. (Advantage: Less "boilerplate code" which essentially just duplicates the list of functions. Disadvantage: Dynamic execution of code always feels a bit "dirty", since you have less compile-time checks.)

Comment: What I am saying is that the whole idea of putting the code to run in a table is a bad idea. I did not vote for a select statement, because that is not a good idea either. I am suggesting that the reason that he wants the code in this way is because it is not properly structured in the first place and adding a further layer of complexity is not going to make life any easier.

Comment: I have never coded public subs, but I did create a module today to complete a scrub of one portion of the main table and I got it to work. I think that I can get this to work, but I still want to be able to dynamically select the combination of acquire, delete, rerun and the corresponding file/object/report....

Comment: rather than store the sql in the table, would it be possible to store the proceedure name, and then dlookup the proceedure name to execute the correct one?

Comment: You can easily run queries by name. Storing the names of the queries you want to run in a table is not a bad idea at all. You can even sensibly select queries from a combo.

Comment: `Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate() ----
    If MsgBox("Run " & Me.Combo0 & "?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then ----
        CurrentDb.Execute Me.Combo0 ----
    End If ----
End Sub`

Comment: The solution I put into play, based on this initial answer : I have created public modules based on the functions that I am attempting to complete; acquire, scrub, export, and database setup. Within each of those modules are a set of public functions, based on my original code, which will execute the desired actions. The initiation button now uses the application.run (function_name) as opposed to the original code running from a single button. I am storing the function_name in a table which allows me to lookup and reuse or cycle through the entire function set as required. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using macros.  You shouldn't need a table.  Also, consider moving your hard-coded SQL to queries.

Comment: This might be a matter of taste, but personally I would advise against macros (VBA code is much more robust) and against action queries (if the SQL is part of a subroutine's functionality, having it "all in one place" makes maintenance a lot easier. *Do* split your code into small subroutines, though!).

Comment: The original version of the database had this all defined in macros and action queries....it had almost 60 action queries to get from end to end. Unfortunately, these are not an option unfortunately. The overall performance was terrible compared to the VBA version that I use now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you shouldn't use a table, just create a module with different subs for each operation. On your button event, after the combo selections, I would  do a case statement.

```
      dim strOperation as string
      strOperation = me!selectionOne
     Select Case strOperation        
    Case "delete": deleteTable(me!selectionTwo)
    Case "export": export(me!selectionTwo)
    case  "acquire": acquire(me!selectionTwo)     
     End Select
```

Of course, you'd have your acquire, delete, and export methods written in a module and have whatever parameters you need for each operation there.

This is just one idea of many that you could use to approach this.

Comment: Scotch, I considered this, but I'm looking for the same code to be reusable in both the end to end process as well as the individual dynamic reuse. Trying to keep the number of lines of code to a minimum

Answer (score 0):

I was going to edit the original answer but this seems to be off on a different tack....

I think it would be best to split the code into functions that return a string if there is an error.  The table you loop through would have a *strFunction,strError* and *strObject* fields.  Your code would loop though the table running each function based on the case statement while passing the *strObject* as a string and then updating *strError* based on any errors you receive.  You could query the table after this process to see which records have errors in them.

If the button is called cmdRunAll here is the code for it.

```
Private Sub cmdRunAll_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblCode", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        With rst
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                .Edit
                Select Case !strFunction
                    Case "fExport"
                        !strError = fExport(!strObject)
                End Select
                .Update
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    MsgBox "Processes complete"
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description & " cmdRunAll_Click " & Me.Name
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Here is a simple sample function

```
Public Function fExport(strTable As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim strError As String
    strError = ""
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , strTable, "C:\users\IusedMyUserNameHere\" & strTable & ".txt"
    fExport = strError
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    strError = Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Function
```